# Express returning 404 for css.map

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using nginx to serve my static content for an express app, this works fine for serving `main.css` however `main.css` is a compiled sass file with a map `main.map.css` which is not being served statically and instead returns a 404 `GET /css/main.css.map 404`.

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # Listens to all domains
    server_name _; 
    # Static folder location in project
    root project/public; 
    # Reverse proxy to express app listening on port 3001
    location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    # Caching 
}
```

My question is how can I make node/express serve the `.css.map` file type statically? Or is there a better way of serving  sass with a map with express.

**EDIT**

The solution was to add the `css.map` type to my nginx cache this means that any of the file types that are cached are not reverse proxied to the express server and instead served by nginx and has the appropriate cache control added

```
    # cache.appcache, HTML and Data
    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
            expires -1;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
              add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|css.map|js)$ { # Added map.css filetype
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
    }
    # WebFonts
     location ~* \.(?:ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: post the nginx config for the static folder

Comment: I've added the nginx config to the question, are you suggesting to create something like a  `location ~* \.(?:css.map)` rule and then pass it to the static folder?

Comment: so that looks like you are using Express to serve static files, not nginx. If that is the case update the question and post the staticfiles config from your app.js

Comment: I have what I assume to be the express static files commented out  `// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: You were correct the header cache-control I overlooked would not pass `.css` `.js` files to express but would pass `css.map`, I've edited it now. Thanks